# I can not find "generate signed apk" in android studio after I load my source code

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, apk, messenger

I got source code from my android developer, then I loaded it using android studio. There is no process sync, the code just loaded successfully.

After that, I tried to produce new APK. Unfortunately the tool does not appear in my android studio, but when I load different source code, the tool appears (generate a signed apk).

I already cleaned and rebuilt the project, but the result is the same. It's not showing generated signed apk.

I searched in build.gradle, inside app folder, and I also found this in configs:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

Answer (score 0):

> rebuild the project

Doesn't generate a new singed APK. Go to > `Build` > `Generate Singed Bundle/APK...`.

 Be sure that you open project with your android studio well.
If it, not an android studio project. You should go to. `File` -> `New` -> `Import Project...`